# Show the error instead of ruby default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When using this I am getting the default design for Ruby on Rails [image]. How can i just print it as regular text in my current design like `<%= error.text %>`?

**Model:**

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :username, :message => "Du skal udfylde brugernavn"
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :username
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index

     if params[:username]
         l = Users.new(:username => params[:username], :password => params[:password], :email => params[:email]).save!

         if Users.save? 
                z = Users.where(:username => params[:username]).limit(1).last
                @debugging="Yay"
         else
                @debugging = user.errors.full_messages.join("<br/>")
         end             
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: you are calling **validates** twice, modify that as `validates_presence_of :username, :message => "Du skal udfylde brugernavn"`

Comment: @SagarBommidi `presence => true` is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In model:**

```
validates_presence_of :username, :message => "Du skal udfylde brugernavn"
```

**In controller:**

```
if user.save
   flash[:success] = 'User saved successfully'
else
   flash[:error] = user.errors.full_messages.join('<br />')
end
```

**Edit**

Not `if Users.save?` it should be `l.save`. (I suggest you to use `User` as model)

```
if params[:username]
   l = Users.new(:username => params[:username], :password => params[:password], :email => params[:email])

   if l.save 
      z = Users.where(:username => params[:username]).limit(1).last
      @debugging="Yay"
   else
      @debugging = l.errors.full_messages.join("<br/>")
   end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't make it. Check my question again for my new code.

Comment: Remove `.save!` from the end

Comment: Thanks so much. Big help. Ruby is nice.

Answer (score 1):

`your_object.errors` returns an associative array : `{:username => "Du skal udfylde brugernavn"}`

So you can do something like :

```
<%= user.errors[:username] %>
```

See more info on how to use this your views here (official Ruby on Rails doc) :
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working-with-validation-errors

Comment: It will still break the page.

Comment: Use Codeit way of saving in your controller. You should use `.save?` in an if statement if you want to check that the save was actually OK. Then display the correct page.

Answer (score 1):

from [Rails Guide to Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validations_overview-errors):

> To verify whether or not a particular attribute of an object is valid, you can use errors[:attribute]. It returns an array of all the errors for :attribute. If there are no errors on the specified attribute, an empty array is returned.

So, just display the `errors` hash..